# Laravel relations and keys for accessing the data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have just set up my first relation in an eloquent model.

```
class Member extends Model
{
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'id', 'person_id');
    }
```

It was a bit confusing at first, because the docs would use member_id in the person table.. but for my db structure this would make no sense.
Anyways I was struggling to show records in an index or form, because I was trying to access person info like this:

```
$member->mobile
```

Instead of

```
$member->person->mobile
```

I would love to get rid of this 'person' in between, just as I had with left joins. Is there a laravel way of doing this? without using left joins. Every time I try to google it, I get the usual eloquent relation stuff. 
Maybe there is an option that already exists... If so I might be writing unnecessary functions, otherwise I might even switch back to using left joins and scopes.
If I keep using this, it will get a lot worse.. for example

```
$member->person->address->street
```

or even 5 in a row which I kinda want to avoid

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to skip specifying the relation name, other than less typing?

Comment: well I realy like to keep my view a bit clean, especialy when working on my smaller screen notebook :S And I've never seen or done differently. Just thought it looked like a big mess :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think this is possible other than creating a new class that aggregates all properties of whatever model you want + properties of relationships. You could also update your model class and override the __get() method and react accordingly, but that sounds like a lot of work too (make sure to call the parent implementation too).

The need to specify the relation name actually makes your code easier to read since `$member->mobile` would look more like a property of your member class. Plus it allows you add additional constraints before retrieving your relation[s]

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: a well, on my last work experience I just saw alot of raw queries and left joins... I geus you have a point, knowing right away where all the data is from. I suppose I can go with it for a while, learn some more relation stuff, and get used to better ways. Ive been working really hard and been learning a lot in a short period of time xD and sometimes there is just no space left in my head haha. Anyways, so far I really enjoy giving every table it's own model. Thinking about it, it makes no sense writing my own functionality over what models have to offer.